# Score-P callpath depth limitation of 30 exceeded

Tags: profiling, profiler, scorep

I am profiling a code with `Scalasca 2.0` that uses some recoursions.

When I run the analyzer with `scalasca -analyze myexec` , it does not rise any error to the end, where it says:

```
Score-P callpath depth limitation of 30 exceeded.
Reached callpath depth was 34
```

At this point, the scalasca results are corrupted and I cannot run `cube` over the produced output files.

I know for sure that the number of self-calls, of the recoursions won't be greater than 34.

I have read that there is a variable taking into account the number of "measured call-paths" (see. https://www.dkrz.de/Nutzerportal-en/doku/blizzard/program-analysis/profiling). So, I also tried to run scalasca with `export ESD_FRAMES=40` but scalasca still says the limit is `30`.

So, Is there a way to shift this scalasca limit to an higher value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write my answer 2 months after you posted the question so chances are you have already found a solution.

In score-p 1.4+ it can be fixed with:

```
export SCOREP_PROFILING_MAX_CALLPATH_DEPTH=128
```

Comment: Thanks you, to solve it I directly wrote to the score-p developers who pointed out this interesting page with all the variables:  https://silc.zih.tu-dresden.de/scorep-current/html/scorpeconfigvariables.html

Comment: Also, there are no `scalasca` or `score-p` tags in StackOverflow, which makes harder for those questions to reach the experts.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin Now we have `scorep` tag.